# AWS API Gateway Cache - Multiple service hits with burst of calls

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, aws-api-gateway

I am working on a mobile app that will broadcast a push message to hundreds of thousands of devices at a time. When each user opens their app from the push message, the app will hit our API for data. The API resource will be identical for each user of this push.

Now let's assume that all 500,000 users open their app at the same time. API Gateway will get 500,000 identical calls.

Because all 500,000 nearly concurrent requests are asking for the same data, I want to cache it. But keep in mind that it takes about 2 seconds to compute the requested value.

**What I want to happen**

I want API Gateway to see that the data is not in the cache, let the first call through to my backend service while the other requests are held in queue, populate the cache from the first call, and then respond to the other 499,999 requests using the cached data.

**What is (seems to be) happening**

API Gateway, seeing that there is no cached value, is sending every one of the 500,000 requests to the backend service! So I will be recomputing the value with some complex db query way more times than resources will allow. This happens because the last call comes into API Gateway before the first call has populated the cache.

Is there any way I can get this behavior?

I know that based on my example that perhaps I could *prime* the cache by invoking the API call myself just before broadcasting the bulk push job, but the actual use-case is slightly more complicated than my simplified example. But rest assured, solving this simplified use-case will solve what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

If you anticipate that kind of burst concurrency, priming the cache yourself is certainly the best option. Have you also considered adding throttling to the stage/method to protect your backend from a large surge in traffic? Clients could be instructed to retry on throttles and they would eventually get a response.

I'll bring your feedback and proposed solution to the team and put it on our backlog.